# Compute $\int \frac{x+3}{\sqrt{x^3+1}} dx$

Tags: calculus, indefinite-integrals

Compute  $\int \frac{x+3}{\sqrt{x^3+1}} dx$

Was thinking about the taylor expansion of $1/\sqrt{x^3+1}$ but is also rather hairy.  Any other tricks?

Comment: Are you looking for an actual anti derivative or for an anti derivative in series form?

Comment: This is an elliptic integral and doesn't have an elementary antiderivative. It can be expressed as hypergeometric functions and be evaluated fast. See [this wiki page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_integral) for details.

Comment: an actual anti derivative

Comment: @WhatsUp mind elaborate a bit?

Comment: @Vendetta I am afraid that ain't gonna work...

Comment: @Vendetta I've given above a relevant wiki page.

Comment: Wolfram|Alpha gives a non-elementary form involving the hypergeometric function $_2F_1$ https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+%28x%2B3%29%2Fsqrt%28x%5E3%2B1%29+dx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By Byrd & Friedman 239.07 and 239.00
$$I=\int_{-1}^y\frac{x+3}{\sqrt{x^3+1}}\,dx=g\left((-1-\sqrt3)F(\varphi,m)+2\sqrt3\int_0^{F(\varphi,m)}\frac1{1+\operatorname{cn}u}\,du+3F(\varphi,m)\right)$$
where the parameter $m$ is $\frac12+\frac{\sqrt3}4$, $\cos\varphi=\operatorname{cn}u=\frac{\sqrt3-1-y}{\sqrt3+1+y}$ and $g=3^{-1/4}$. B&F 341.53 solves the second integral, yielding after some simplification
$$I=g((2+\sqrt3)F(\varphi,m)-2\sqrt3E(\varphi,m))+\frac{2\sqrt{y^3+1}}{\sqrt3+1+y}$$

Answer (score 0):

Using series is not bad since
$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{x^3+1}}=\frac 1{\sqrt{\pi } }\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n\frac{ \left(n-\frac{1}{2}\right)! }{ n!} x^{3n}$$
So
$$\frac{x+3}{\sqrt{x^3+1}}=\frac 1{\sqrt{\pi } }\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n\frac{ \left(n-\frac{1}{2}\right)! }{ n!} x^{3n+1}+\frac 3{\sqrt{\pi } }\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n\frac{ \left(n-\frac{1}{2}\right)! }{ n!} x^{3n}$$
Just integrate termwise and this gives you the expansion of some nasty elliptic integral.